# Weasyprint output not displaying most of the original webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, weasyprint

I have a python webscraper that collects municipal data. The website itself does not have an integrated method of downloading the data, so I have written a script to save and download the html page as a pdf using weasyprint. However, the webpage looks like this in the pdf output:

[image: pdfoutput]

This is how the webpage looks in a browser:
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix the pdf output so that the information in the table under "Permits Issued in the past 30 days" displays correctly?

Script code:

```
from classes.main import *
import weasyprint
import datetime

#Opening website 
url = "https://www.dnv.org/property-development/look-building-and-trades-permits"

with Display(visible=False, size=(1200,1500)):
  print("display initiated")
  browser.get(url)
  print("browser loaded")

  #Wait for page to load
  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-content")))
  print("Page loaded")

  browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lastcalendardays"]').click()
  sleep(2)

  current_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
  current_date_and_time_string = str(current_date_and_time)

  pdf = weasyprint.HTML('https://www.dnv.org/property-development/look-building-and-trades-permits').write_pdf()
  open('/bm/data/' + current_date_and_time_string + ' - northvandistrict' + '.pdf', 'wb').write(pdf)

print("end of code")
browser.quit()
```